# Hint Needed for a Decreasing Sequence of Limit Points

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

I'm trying to work through exercise 13E, part (4) of S. Willard's *Topology* through self-study.  I'm scratching my head on the question below.  I paraphrased of some notation earlier in the exericse, which is required to understand the question.

> Given a set $A$, let $A'$ denote the set of accumulation points of $A$.  Let $A^1 = A', A^2 = (A^1)', A^3 = (A^2)'$ and so on . . . .
>
> For any positive integer $n$, there is a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $A,A^1,\ldots,A^{n-1}$ are non-empty and $A^n = \emptyset$.

Of course, we assume $\mathbb{R}$ has the standard topology.

I'm scratching my head trying to construct such a set $A$.  I've thought about taking the union of some collection of sets, each in a form similar to $\{ 1/n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, and arranging the limit points thereof so they fall off one by one as I continue to find the limit points of the limit points.  I haven't found a way to make this work, though, and I have a feeling I'm heading in the wrong direction.

Can someone please provide me a hint or some guidance?  I'd like to work this out myself, so please do no provide a solution (or if you do, please conceal it as a spoiler).  I appreciate your assistance.

Best,
Doug

Comment: If we take $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ to be any sequence with limit $L$ and $A = \{L\} \cup \{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$, wouldn't you have $A' = \{L\}$?

Comment: Have you considered an induction proof? Given an arbitrary set $B$, can you construct a set $A$ such that $A'=B$?

Comment: Following Karl's hint, consider the following situation: check that if $B$ is *nice enough*, you can produce $A$ such that $(i)$ $A$ is *nice enough* and $(ii)$ $A' = B$. Then, if you find some *nice enough* subset for which $B' = \emptyset$; iterate the aforementioned process.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a schematic of what you need to get the case $n=4$ in the plane; it generalizes easily and also adapts fairly easily to $\Bbb R$.

$$\begin{array}{rr}
\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\bullet\\
\uparrow&\uparrow&\uparrow&\uparrow\\
\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet\\
\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet\\
\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet\\
\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet\\
\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet
\end{array}$$